# to make a column into multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table structure

```
NAME    SALES   STORE
A       10      STORE1
A       10      STORE2
B       20      STORE1
B       20      STORE2
```

I want the data to be in the below format using select query.

```
NAME    STORE1  STORE2
A       10      10
B       20      20
```

I used the pivot, but getting zero in place of STORE2 in first row,zero in place of STORE1 in second row.

Can anybody help with this.

Comment: Please show your query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the store's are minimal then you can do conditional aggregation :

```
select name, 
       sum(case when store = 'store1' then sales else 0 end) as store1,
       sum(case when store = 'store2' then sales else 0 end) as store2
from t 
group by name;
```

Comment: I have given only minimal columns -  3 columns, however, we select more columns, so group by not working

Comment: @Selva: You are mistaken. This is just another way to write a pivot query. In both queries you must know which stores you want to show in your select. If you need more columns in `GROUP BY`, add them there. If you want to show more stores, add them in the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: Sorry for mistake Yogesh. I got it after Thorsten clarification. Thanks both of you

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the pivot clause like below :

```sql
with t (NAME, SALES, STORE) as (
select 'A', 10, 'STORE1' from dual union all
select 'A', 10, 'STORE2' from dual union all
select 'B', 20, 'STORE1' from dual union all
select 'B', 20, 'STORE2' from dual
)
select NAME, STORE1, STORE2
from t
pivot (
sum(SALES) for STORE in ('STORE1' as STORE1, 'STORE2' as STORE2)
)
;
```

Comment: Glad to see I could help